# Whats wrong with this JSON string?

Tags: php, json, jsondecoder

I'm trying decoding and accessing the JSON object values from this string, but json_decode in PHP is unable to decode it.

```
{"next_page": "Y", "search_results": [{"name": "Apple iPhone X, Fully 
 Unlocked 5.8\", 64 GB - Silver", "asin": "B075QN8NDH", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41P889KMNiL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 8 4.7\", 64 GB, Fully Unlocked, Gold", "asin": 
 "B075QJSQLH", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YkkxsF4xL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone X, GSM Unlocked 5.8\", 256 GB - Space Gray", "asin": 
 "B075QMZH2L", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YP-wmuPSL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone SE 16 GB Factory Unlocked, Silver (Certified 
 Refurbished)", "asin": "B01GXAT0D8", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51+VKJJMWAL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6 Unlocked Smartphone, 16 GB (Gold) (Certified 
 Refurbished)", "asin": "B00YD545CC", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51BbI-8wpTL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 4S 16 GB AT&T, Black", "asin": "B005SSAXSI", 
 "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41eVAfYDANL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 7 , GSM Unlocked, 32GB - Rose Gold (Certified 
 Refurbished)", "asin": "B01N9YOF3R", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517xB8vSCML._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 8 4.7\", 64 GB, GSM Unlocked, Space Gray", "asin": 
 "B075QNGDZ9", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41sfP+0QSvL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 8 a1905 64GB GSM Unlocked (Certified Refurbished)", 
 "asin": "B078P5BK5G", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qBAk8HvqL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 8 Plus 5.5\", 64 GB, Fully Unlocked, Gold", "asin": 
 "B075QNGHS8", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41AAYX09kZL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6S PLUS 16GB (Rose Gold) Factory Unlocked", "asin": 
 "B015E8VWEU", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31X7-Lq6FIL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6 Plus 16GB GSM Unlocked Smartphone - Silver 
 (Certified Refurbished)", "asin": "B00YD54HZ2", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51EHOptBcIL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6s 128GB Factory Unlocked (Space Gray)", "asin": 
 "B015E8UKNE", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41NI83uayEL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Huawei Mate 9 with Amazon Alexa and Leica Dual Camera - 64GB 
 Unlocked Phone - Moonlight Silver (US Warranty)", "asin": "B01N1JV80Z", 
 "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qpONRrJBL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6s 16GB Space Gray, Verizon Wireless", "asin": 
 "B075H4C3L4", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/412W-f+wNqL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Honor 6X Unlocked Smartphone, Dual Lens Camera and Dual SIM 
 Standby, 3GB RAM, 32 GB ROM, Gray", "asin": "B01MRZFBBH", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51y5Cu+v8dL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6 (GSM Unlocked), 64GB, Space Gray", "asin": 
 "B00NQGP5X2", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51We979ipcL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6S Plus, GSM Unlocked, 16GB - Silver (Certified 
 Refurbished)", "asin": "B01JAWWVXW", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41f0V8ZqgML._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "BLU VIVO X \u2013 6.0\u201d HD+18:9 Display Smartphone with Dual 
 Front and Rear Cameras \u2013Black", "asin": "B0795W4SRD", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ftij8famL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6S - 128GB GSM Unlocked - Silver (Certified 
 Refurbished)", "asin": "B01M0L5JFB", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/415ui3Im4kL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 8 Plus 256gb Black Unlocked", "asin": "B075NVNBCW", 
 "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31QhJKIvfLL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 4S 64 GB  Unlocked GSM , Black", "asin": 
 "B005UEF72M", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S6fyTccFL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "HTC One M9 6535L 32GB Verizon Octa-Core Android Smartphone W/ 20MP 
 Camera - Silver/Rose God (Certified Refurbished)", "asin": "B013QB52VQ", 
 "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/518IUgM7NlL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6S Plus 16 GB Unlocked, Gold International Version", 
 "asin": "B015E8VE6Q", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41gf4ZVplhL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 4S 16 GB Factory Unlocked", "asin": "B0149UISAK", 
 "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41u6Vx+mxRL._AC_US160_.jpg"}, 
 {"name": "Apple iPhone 6 64 GB Unlocked, Gold (Refurbished)", "asin": 
 "B00VIINO7O", "image_url": 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51y-UmFbjzL._AC_US160_.jpg"}]}
```

This JSON is returned from a python script which is scraping the amazon.
I used stripslashes in PHP to remove slashes but json_decode  is not returning anything.
Any Idea how to do it  ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a string. Looks like an object already.

Comment: It doesn't give any errors. Try here: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: Actually, when I repasted it, it gave an error :)

Comment: Its not formatted properly check here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Try this `$result = json_decode('['.str_replace("\n", '', $your_json_str).']', true);`

Comment: A Properly formatted json will not give you error [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8GuYp1VT) link here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your string has new line on it.

I tried the code below and works fine:

```
$str = '{"next_page": "Y", "search_results": [{"name": "Ap....'; /* Your json string here*/
$str = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $str);
$arr = json_decode( $str, true );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```